# users being kicked out of windows 2012 r2 server at 8,12 and 16:00. when this happens connection to server is lost

Tags: windows

users are being kicked out of the server exactly after every four hours ie 8 am, 12mid day and 4 pm. when I cant ping the server during this time because the connection will be lost. tried to check for scheduled tasks and disable them but its still happening

Comment: Did you check the event log? Did you check the network hardware?